# How to make all the exponents same size?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, overbrace

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
a^9 \cdot a^{99} \cdot a^{999} \cdot a^{9999} \cdots 
   a^{\overbrace{999 \cdots 9}^{\text{10 digits}}}=a^x
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Use `\scriptstyle`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[a^9 \cdot a^{99} \cdot a^{999} \cdot a^{9999} \cdots 
a^{\overbrace{\scriptstyle 999 \cdots 9}^{\text{10 digits}}}=a^x\]
\end{document}`. And please do not use `$$ ... $$` but `\[ ... \]` as in the above example.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend not using `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` directly, because they can have bad effects on spacing.

Here's a version that changes sizes when in subscripts or superscripts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oubr@demote}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\obr}[2]{{\mathpalette\oubr@over{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\oubr@over}[2]{\oubr@@over#1#2}
\newcommand{\oubr@@over}[3]{\overbrace{#1#2}^{\oubr@demote#1#3}}
\newcommand{\ubr}[2]{{\mathpalette\oubr@under{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\oubr@under}[2]{\oubr@@under#1#2}
\newcommand{\oubr@@under}[3]{\underbrace{#1#2}_{\oubr@demote#1#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\ubr{a^9 \cdot a^{99} \cdot a^{999} \cdot a^{9999} \cdots 
     a^{\obr{999 \cdots 9}{\text{10 digits}}}}
    {\text{umpteen times}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]